# Read json value as nvarchar2

Tags: json, oracle

How can I read JSON value as NVARCHAR2 variable type with json_object_t?
Lets say I have a blob that contains json:

```
 [{"NAME1":"ĄŚĆĘąśćę"},{"NAME2":"ЙйКкЛлМм"}]
```

Will parse it as `json_object_t(parse(blob))`.
I want to access NAME2, but there is no NVARCHAR2 type return procedure on that json_object_t, only get_string(key), which outputs VARCHAR2.

Database characterset for VARCHAR2 is EEISO8859P2, for NVARCHAR2 is AL16UTF16.
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `to_nchar(your_json_object.get_clob(key))`?

Comment: No luck, but thanks for advice.